# How can record audio and video with ffmpeg at the same time?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I want to record with the hard device in my os:

```
lsusb | rg -i camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2bdf:0284 SN0002 HIK 1080P CAMERA
```

It is a web-camera.

`video` can be recorded in my os with the ffmpeg command without audio:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 output.mkv
```

`audio` can be recorded in my os with the ffmpeg command without video:

```
ffmpeg -f alsa  -i default  output.mp3
```

I want to record audio and video at the same time with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i default  output.mkv
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i default -c:v libx264 -c:a flac -r 30 output.mkv
```

All the command can record video without audio,why `ffmpeg -f alsa  -i default  output.mp3` can recodr audio then?How can add the audio capture into ffmpeg with video capture?

I retry with `Jaromanda X`'s mention:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -i default  -map 0:v -map 1:a  output.mkv
```

It record both audio and video now ,but strange that it only record the first sentence when i speak four sentences loudly to the web-camera !!!

Comment: Does it has to be command-line or are GUI [option](https://obsproject.com/)s fine as well?

Comment: @DannyNiu - ffmepg doesn't have a GUI

Comment: try adding `-map 0:v -map 1:a`

Comment: @JaromandaX I linked to OBS project in my comment in case you missed the underline in the word "option".

Comment: @DannyNiu - as there's no mention of OBS in the question, it's irrelevant. Why would anyone install OBS, and potentially a whole GUI environment just to mux an audio and video stream?

Comment: @Jaromanda X,so strange that i can only record part of audio!

Comment: part of audio? I thought you said there was **no** audio

Comment: It record both audio and video now ,but strange that it only record the first sentence when i speak four sentences loudly to the web-camera !!!